# How to keep a variable handy across a number of controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've moved an application to using ActiveResource and I'm finding that I need to rethink the way I've taught myself to do some things, and I'm searching for the best way to go about this.

For example, I need to keep a query handy say @current_account which I've done as

```
@current_account ||= Account.where(etc etc)
```

in an applicationcontroller.rb for a certain scope. This isn't all that useful with AR, because the call to the API is made each time. I'd like to minimize calls to the api (especially where I have other more expensive calls I don't want run on every query, I want to run them once and keep them handy)

So, what is the Rails way? I have to keep a variable with an AR call to an API handy from the ApplicationController in a certain scope, across several other controllers without having to write it out each time (or call the API each time, or put it in a user accesible session because it isn't exactly text/strings, it is objects I need to use).

I'm curious about how others do this, if I should or should not be doing this, what is the right DRY way, etc. So this is somewhat open-ended.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Stop asking duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370514/activeresource-caching

Comment: This was meant to have a wider scope within the context of Rails application programming, so no. Take some time to read instead of shallow scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to create a module for this kind of behavior:

```
module CustomAuth
  def self.included(controller)
    controller.send :helper_method, :current_account, :logged_in?
  end

  def current_account
    # note the Rails.cache.fetch. First time, it will
    # make a query, but it caches the result and not
    # run the query a second time.
    @current_account ||= Rails.cache.fetch(session[:account_id], Account.where(...))
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_account.nil?
  end
end
```

Then, make sure that Rails loads up this file (I put mine in `./lib/custom_auth.rb`), so add that to the `config.autoload_paths` in `./config/application.rb`:

```
# ./config/application.rb
...
config.autoload_path += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
...
```

Import the `CustomAuth` module into your `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CustomAuth
  protect_from_forgery

  ...
end
```

Finally, Crucial: **Restart your server**

NOTE: You can add additional methods to the `custom_auth.rb`. If you restart the server, they will be available. These methods are also available in the view, so you can call `current_account.name` right inside a view.

Comment: This is the "DRYest" way that I know of. You have all your authentication namespaced in a single module. You aren't cluttering up `application_controller.rb` with authentication logic, etc.